# Big users table or split in 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following users table:

[image]

Half from Ion_Auth Codeigniter and half custom fields.

Should I split the table in 2? And store user details in the main table and in the second user activity like the count of likes, number of questions and answers and backgrounds?

[image]

Comment: I wouldn’t store like counts in your user table at all. That data can quickly get out of date. Instead, fetch the number of likes via a method in your user model and cache it to avoid hitting the data and re-calculating each time.

Comment: I store the likes in like table and for each insert with a trigger i make a + 1 in users table. It`s not ok?

Comment: @IonVasile you generate a lot of unnecessary actions. Such counts could be visible through a view. Do not store them in your table.

Comment: And what happens if your trigger fails…? Or you forget to add a trigger for when a specific entity is liked? Just don’t store counts. You’ll going to end up with data integrity issues at some point.

Comment: And you suggest to count them every time? In likes table if I have milions of likes and I make a query; SELECT COUNT() as number FROM likes WHERE question_id = 10; would have a lot of timing to get the results.

Comment: @MartinBean Can you explain me please a case when a trigger fails? In what scenario?

Comment: “And you suggest to count them every time?” No. I didn’t. I clearly stated to count once, and then **cache**.

Comment: After a lot of thinking I don`t know if cache is a good method for me and let me explain:

If people only view the the page with questions would be ok because instead of select data from database would get from cache.

Assuming that the like button is pressed every second on my website. So on that insert I must delete the cache from the server to make new one with the new count yes? So every second the cache will be deleted and replaced with new one. Would be this ok? I use codeigniter so I use $this->db->cache_on(); and $this->db->cache_delete('stream', 'question'); to delete cache.